# IIS SubApplication running .NET 4.5.1 under Classic ASP web appliccation

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, asp.net-web-api2

we have a painful legacy web application running a mixture of classic ASP and .net 3.5.  **How can we get a .NET 4.5.1 application to run as an IIS sub-application to the classic ASP application?**

Our goals are:

- Use WebAPI2 to create a Angular.js application
- use parent application for user login
- link to new application from existing application.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the location attribute at the web.config? Further details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.85).aspx).

I mean, you can put a web.config within your new Application folder and override some settings. Something like this:

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime />
        ....... more stuff

    </system.web>   
</location>
```